# Htaccess Redirect a folder and exclude two subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't figure our RewriteRule so I've tried RedirectMatch. I need to match to a folder `/2018/` and all other sub-folders but I do not want to redirect `/2018/speakers/` or `/2018/events/`

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/2018/$^(speakers|events)($|/) https://example.com/north-america
```

Doesn't seem to work and I really can't figure out how to exclude after an include. Thanks for any help!

If it must be Rewrite Rule here is the rest of the top portion. I need to do this for multiple years like 2017, 2016 etc so maybe this is the best way to do it.

```
# Force https

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Pagely-SSL} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RewriteCond` to exclude some URLs

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2018/(speakers|events)
RewriteRule ^/?2018/(.+) https://example.com/north-america/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Line 1: if the request uri is not starting with `/2018/speakers` or `/2018/events`

Line 2: if the request uri is starting with `/2018/`, then redirect to `https://example.com/north-america/` permanently. `$1` is the backreference to `(.+)`.